# Can't adding objects to MutableArray with iOS Parse SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I am newbie on Objective C and Parse.com

I want to add my string values from parse to my NSMutableArray.But I couldn't add there are my codes.

```
-(void)getObjectsFromParseOnline: (NSString *)objectID {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Veterinerler"];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectID block:^(PFObject *vet, NSError *error) {

        if ([vet[@"isMember"]isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {

            [veterinerAdi addObject:vet[@"adi"]];
            [veterinerAdres addObject:vet[@"adres"]];
            [veterinerTel addObject:vet[@"telefon"]];
            [veterinerWeb addObject:vet[@"web"]];
            [veterinerFace addObject:vet[@"face"]];
            [veterinerLat addObject:vet[@"latitude"]];
            [veterinerLong addObject:vet[@"longitude"]];
            [geceAcik addObject:vet[@"geceAcik"]];

            [vet pinInBackground];
        }
    }];
}
```

and I call this method from my viewDidLoad method.

```
veterinerAdi = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
veterinerAdres = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
veterinerTel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
veterinerWeb = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
veterinerFace = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
veterinerLat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
veterinerLong = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
geceAcik = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 [self getObjectsFromParseOnline:@"OqfFYACIpr"];

2015-02-23 22:18:35.489 VetMapp[4345:172731] THIS IS THE NSLOG RESULTS = (
)
```

It's empty...

What is the problem ? is this a bug or something ?

Many Thanks !

Comment: Have you verified that your if condition is actually true and the code reaches the point where it adds the objects to your array?

Comment: yea if statement is working fine i tried many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that you log the results of an async function before it even returns. Loading the objects from parse is done asynchronously, so if you do a `NSLog(@"%@", yourArray)` directly after calling `[self getObjectsFromParseOnline:@"OqfFYACIpr"]`, the array you log will be empty as the network request might not be finished yet.

If you move your NSLog inside the callback of `getObjectInBackgroundWithId:` and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you ! Yea it was a async function problem. I couldn't see my array items in my table view, so i added [self.tableView reloadData]; its perfectly working now. Thank you !